# How to allow an anonymous user access to some given page in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have enabled form authentication in my ASP.NET MVC web application. I want to allow  anonymous users access only to some specific pages, including Register.cshtml for instance. I was able to allow access to my CSS-file from my root web.config by doing this.

```
<location path="Content/Site.css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Now I want to allow anonymous access to other pages, like Home and Register. Do any body know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In MVC you normally use the `[Authorize]` attribute to manage authorization. Controllers or individual actions that are dressed with that attribute will require that the user is authorized in order to access them - all other actions will be available to anonymous users.

In other words, a black-list approach, where actions that require authorization are black-listed for anonymous users using `[Authorize]` - all actions (not dressed with the attribute) will be available.

**Update:**

With MVC4 a new attribute has been introduced, namely the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. Together with the `[Authorize]` attribute, you can now take a white-list approach instead. The white-list approach is accomplished by dressing the entire controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute, to force authorization for all actions within that controller. You can then dress specific actions, that shouldn't require authorization, with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, and thereby white-listing only those actions. With this approach, you can be confident that you don't, by accident, forget to dress an action with the `[Authorize]`, leaving it available to anyone, even though it shouldn't.

Your code could then be something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller {

   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult LogIn () {
      // This action can be accessed by unauthorized users
   }

   public ActionResult UserDetails () {
      // This action can NOT be accessed by unauthorized users
   }
}
```

Comment: :if this is case why is it that i can't see my Register.cshtml. when i only just enable the form authentication.

Comment: @JED Not sure, you probably need to complement your question with some more context in order to solve that. Do you get any errors, or what happens when you try to access your register-view?

Comment: i think i know what the problem is. i deny all user access in my config

Answer (score 17):

In the Web.config i had the below authorization

```
<authorization>
    <deny users ="?"/>
</authorization>
```

this causes the

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

not work correctly, i had to remove that authorization of my Web.config, and in all the controllers put the line

```
[Authorize]
```

before the declaration of the class, to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me! Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, I hope the info was useful for more Developers.