# ASP.NET MVC Authorize attribute from outside DOM/Session

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, in which one of my controllers use the [Authorize] attribute to ensure the user has logged in.

Now, I would very much like to call this controller, from another context (in which the DOM/session in unavailable). I *can* save an earlier Auth Ticket, but how do I include it in future requests to my controller?

Comment: If you are using your controller method outside of the MVC pipeline, then the Authorize attribute won't even do anything unless you are doing something additional to invoke action filters?

Comment: It tries to redirect me to the Login view

Comment: how about the [AllowAnonymous]  attribute??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727509/how-to-allow-an-anonymous-user-access-to-some-given-page-in-mvc

Comment: How are you attempting to call the controller?  Can you post the code in question?

Comment: You can easily reproduce this. Make any controller, and add the [Authorize] tag to it. Then try to call that controller from e.g. cURL or similar. You will be redirected to the login view. Im asking how to include the auth ticket in my request.

Comment: This is what you're looking for http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api