# Too many redirects error (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC app and I try to access mobile area.

So I decided to use integrated to chrome mobile mode.

My start controller is `Account/Login`

Here is code of `ApplicationStart`

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
#if DEBUG
            XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logging_DEBUG.config")));
#else
            if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Contains("DevTrackerweb")
               || AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Contains("Trackerweb4Test"))
            {
                XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logging_DEBUG.config")));
            }
            else
                XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logging.config")));
#endif

            var log = LogManager.GetLogger(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            log.Info("Application start");

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new NullableDecimalModelBinder());

            Translator.Prefetch().Wait();

            HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("TrackerwebServiceStatus", TrackerwebServiceStatus.OK);

            sitesByHostName = InitializeSites();
            mainCustomerIDByCustomerID = InitializeCustomerIDDictionary();
        }
```

When I run it, I have this

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your login page/action is not configured for anonymous access.  Try adding the [`AllowAnonymous`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute to the Login action method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727509/how-to-allow-an-anonymous-user-access-to-some-given-page-in-mvc

For example like this?

Comment: Okay, I will try

Answer (score 0):

So problem was in that it was legacy code and I have MvcSiteMap extension ,that I deleted.

In web config I had some code related to this extension and when I deleted it all okay