# AWS SDK can't find default credentials when using remote Powershell via WinRM unless user has logged in manually

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm, aws-sdk-net

I'm having a very odd issue. I have two Windows servers (2022 Datacenter). ServerA and ServerB. As part of an automated deployment process ServerA uses a remote (WinRM) Powershell session into ServerB to execute a script. This script needs to connect to an Amazon AWS S3 bucket to download some files. I added the AWS credentials as "default" to ServerB, but it throws this error:

```
Get-S3Object : No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
```

However, if you remote-desktop into ServerB using the same (local) account and run Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail you can see the default credentials in the result, stored within the AWS SDK cache.

But then - this is the odd part - if you now initiate the original script on ServerA it works! It's like you need to have physically logged in as the target account on ServerB to get the credentials to load, somehow.

I've tried forcing the issue by adding lines like the following to the script:

```
$ENV:AWS_PROFILE = "default"
$ENV:AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE = "default"
Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName default

$object = Get-S3Object [...]
```

But I just get different errors saying the profile can't be found! Note that all other aspects of this script work whether or not the Remote Desktop session is/has-been initiated, it is only the AWS SDK part that has this issue.

Comment: I think you will need to initialise the SDK Credential cache - or use one of the more primitive/insecure options to store the creds like environment variables or a credential file in homedir for WinRM. SDK cache is an encrypted file in appdata so there might be a service you could `start-service` or some other dependency thats normally met by the act of logging in. You might need to use the dotnet sdk (embed a few lines of c# in powershell) to force the SDK to load the credentials properly. Also check windows Event logs and enable `-verbose` output for more clues

Comment: See https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/credential-loading-and-the-aws-sdk-for-dotnet-deep-dive for an overview of available mechinisms/some sample code

Comment: You want Anonymous.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727509/how-to-allow-an-anonymous-user-access-to-some-given-page-in-mvc