Deployed azure functions returns 404 Not Found error
Today I created many functions with Entity Framework and postgres and tested them all on localhost. So I deployed to Azure and when I tested it on the Azure Portal, everything is returning 404. I've tried many things and nothing has resolved it. Please can someone help me solve this problem.
My function looks like:
public class CityFunction
    {
        private readonly CityService _cityService;

        public CityFunction()
        {
            var dbContext = new AppDbContext();
            _cityService = new CityService(dbContext);
        }

        private JsonSerializerOptions GetJsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            return new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                WriteIndented = true,
                ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
            };
        }

[FunctionName("FindCityById")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FindCityById(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "cities/{idCity:int}")]
                HttpRequest req,
            int idCity,
            ILogger log
        )
        {
            var city = await _cityService.FindCityById(idCity);
            var jsonSerializerOptions = GetJsonSerializerOptions();
            var jsonResponse = JsonSerializer.Serialize(city, jsonSerializerOptions);
            return city != null
                ? new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = jsonResponse,
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    StatusCode = 200,
                }
                : new NotFoundResult();
        }


Try adding logging to your various code paths

You need to use [AllowAnonymous]. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727509/how-to-allow-an-anonymous-user-access-to-some-given-page-in-mvc

If you look at the Portal inside the Function resource, in the "Overview" you should see a list of the functions detected. Does this list contain the function you are trying to access? If not there is something wrong with the deployment.

@JulianHüppauff, yes, all my functions are listed. And right now I just tried to deploy a simple function that only returns true, and it also returns 404. Do you know which configuration could be doing this?

If you select any of those functions, you should come to a page where you can select "Get function url" try to reach the function via this option.
To double check, you haven't changed anything in regards to the default route?
So your function should be reachable via https://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>

@JulianHüppauff, I've checked this, and the url path ir right. I have no idea about what is happening.

Given code is for In-Process model

Make sure you have selected In-Process version.

Below given code worked for me:
I just used
public  Function1(CityService cityService)
  { 
      _cityService = cityService;
  }

in place of
public CityFunction()
        {
            var dbContext = new AppDbContext();
            _cityService = new CityService(dbContext);
        }

Function1.cs:
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace dotnet8_inprocess
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly CityService _cityService;

        public Function1(CityService cityService)
        {
            _cityService = cityService;
        }

        private JsonSerializerOptions GetJsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            return new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                WriteIndented = true,
                ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
            };
        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "cities/{idCity:int}")] HttpRequest req, int idCity,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var city = await _cityService.FindCityById(idCity);
            var jsonSerializerOptions = GetJsonSerializerOptions();
            var jsonResponse = JsonSerializer.Serialize(city, jsonSerializerOptions);
            return city != null
                ? new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = jsonResponse,
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    StatusCode = 200,
                }
                : new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}

dotnet8_inprocess:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>dotnet8_inprocess</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

My Data :
postgres=> select * From city;
 id |    name     | population | countrycode |         createdat          
----+-------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------
  1 | Los Angeles |    3980400 | USA         | 2024-09-17 04:35:54.869276
  2 | Tokyo       |   37435191 | JPN         | 2024-09-17 04:35:54.869276
  3 | London      |    8982000 | GBR         | 2024-09-17 04:35:54.869276
  4 | New Delhi   | 1413644826 | IND         | 2024-09-17 04:35:54.869276
(4 rows)

OUTPUT:
Local :


Azure :


